# Wait time probability

Tags: probability

I have an exponential distribution with a mean of $10$ minutes which represents the probability of time your order will take to process at a pharmacy.

What is the probability that the total time taken to process the orders of the next two customers, assuming independence, is more than $20$ minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent continuous random variables with the density functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$. Let $Z=X+Y$. The density function of the random variable $Z$ is given by
$$
f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy.
$$
Then the probability
$$
\Pr\{Z>20\}=\int_{20}^{+\infty}f_Z(z)\mathrm dz.
$$

Comment: The density function for Z, you integrate with respect to y, why isn't it integrate with respect x also if Z = X + Y?

Comment: @Tom That's the convolution of two density functions (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) for more details). How do you suggest we integrate with respect to $x$ also?

Comment: So as long as X and Y are the same density functions you can integrate with respect to either variable.

Comment: Just trying to understand. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Tom Yes, you're right. $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(z-x) f_X(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z-y) f_Y(y)\mathrm dy$. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000501/intuition-behind-convolution-of-sum-of-two-densities) for an intuitive interpretation.

Comment: When I find f<sub>Z</sub>(z) it gives me a function with infinity. Is this right?

Comment: @Tom What do you mean by function with infinity? Did you adjust the limits of integration? $f_X(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ if $y<0$. Hence, $f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)=0$ if $y\notin[0,z]$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy=\int_0^zf_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy$.

Comment: My mistake was setting the upper limit to infinity not z